# Downloading the full texts for the whole database in JabRef-3.3

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, jabref, paper

Using JabRef v3.3, I can easily search the scientific paper on the internet in save it into bibtex database. But when I try to download the full text for the whole database, I met some trouble.

By searching the internet, I have been told that the local copy as an external program for `find the full text` tool should be installed in the `plugin ->Manage Plugins`. But I can't find a way to install the .jar external program in the version 3.3 (I couldn't find the **plug-in** option).

I use **quality -> look up full texts document** instead, but it seems like I would only download one `.pdf` per time.

So, how to download all the related files for one **.bib** database. Any advice would be appreciate!

Comment: Maybe you should rather ask this at a JabRef related place like https://sourceforge.net/p/jabref/discussion/

Comment: Can you please open a new issue at the official support page https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are working on adding such a feature. Keep an eye on https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/1323

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will notice the news of this great tool.